# Is the Writer Monad effectively the same as the State Monad?

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz, state-monad, writer-monad

There's a great tutorial [here](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Writer.html) that seems to suggest to me that the Writer Monad is basically a special case tuple object that does operations on behalf of  (A,B).   The writer accumulates values on the left (which is A) and that A has a corresponding Monoid with it (hence it can accumulate or mutate state).  If A is a collection, then it accumulates.

The State Monad is also a object that deals with an internal tuple.  They both can be flatMap'd, map'd, etc.  And the operations seem the same to me.  How are they different?  (please respond back with a scala example, I'm not familiar with Haskel). Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Your intuition that these two monads are closely related is exactly right. The difference is that `Writer` is much more limited, in that it doesn't allow you to read the accumulated state (until you cash out at the end). The only thing you can do with the state in a `Writer` is tack more stuff onto the end.

More concisely, `State[S, A]` is a kind of wrapper for `S => (S, A)`, while `Writer[W, A]` is a wrapper for `(W, A)`.

Consider the following usage of `Writer`:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def addW(x: Int, y: Int): Writer[List[String], Int] =
  Writer(List(s"$x + $y"), x + y)

val w = for {
  a <- addW(1, 2)
  b <- addW(3, 4)
  c <- addW(a, b)
} yield c
```

Now we can run the computation:

```
scala> val (log, res) = w.run
log: List[String] = List(1 + 2, 3 + 4, 3 + 7)
res: Int = 10
```

We could do exactly the same thing with `State`:

```
def addS(x: Int, y: Int) =
  State((log: List[String]) => (log |+| List(s"$x + $y"), x + y))

val s = for {
  a <- addS(1, 2)
  b <- addS(3, 4)
  c <- addS(a, b)
} yield c
```

And then:

```
scala> val (log, res) = s.run(Nil)
log: List[String] = List(1 + 2, 3 + 4, 3 + 7)
res: Int = 10
```

But this is a little more verbose, and we could also do *lots* of other things with `State` that we couldn't do with `Writer`.

So the moral of the story is that you should use `Writer` whenever you can—your solution will be cleaner, more concise, and you'll get the satisfaction of having used the appropriate abstraction.

Very often `Writer` won't give you all the power you need, though, and in those cases `State` will be waiting for you.

Answer (score 1):

*tl;dr State is Read and Write while Writer is, well, only write.*

With State you have access to the previous data stored and you can use this data in your current computation:

```
def myComputation(x: A) =
  State((myState: List[A]) => {
        val newValue = calculateNewValueBasedOnState(x,myState)
        (log |+| List(newValue), newValue)
  })
```

With Writer you can store data in some object you don't have access to, you can only write to that object.

Comment: The other answer seems to suggest that the Writer allows reading the accumulated value 1 time at the end: `in that it doesn't allow you to read the accumulated state (until you cash out at the end)`. How would accumulating some value but never being able to read it make sense?

Comment: @RăzvanFlaviusPanda I think a logger is the standard example for the writer, in that case you want to write to a file or a third party system and the rest of program should not care or access the logs.